# What exception would be thrown in a @Transactional method if a database connection is unavailable?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Using `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` with

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="txMgr">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emFactory"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="txMgr"/>
```

What exception would be thrown upon entering the `@Transactional` method, if any?

Comment: Depends on the connector being used.  I would bet a lot of money that it will contain something like "database connection unavailable"

Comment: What I can tell you is it will start with `org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException`.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a subclass of RuntimeException.

This has to be managed at a higher level than your service.
If the database is KO, rollbacking is irrelevant ^^.